# Atomic data reaggregation with Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

We've implemented batch processing with apache spark. One batch appears once in 15 minutes and contains around 5GB of data in parquet format. We are storing data partitioned with schema

```
/batch=11/dt=20170102/partition=2
```

batch is monotonically increasing number, dt is date,partition is a number from 0 to 30 partitioned by clientid, it's needed for faster querying. 
Mainly data is being searched from this structure by date and/or by clientid. From this folder we are preparing additional transformations using batch id as pointer. 
For one day we get 3000 (100 batcher per day) folders and around 3000000 files inside. After some time we want to make bigger batches in order to reduce amount of folders and files stored in hdfs. 
For example from

```
/batch=100/dt=.../partition=...
...
/batch=9999/dt=.../partition=...
```

we want to make

```
/batch=9999/dt=20170102/partition=...
/batch=9999/dt=20170103/partition=...
etc...
```

But problem is that users can run queries on this folder, and if we will move data between batches clients can read the same data twice or didn't read at all.
Can you suggest any appropriate solution how to tighten batches in atomic way? Or may be you can suggest better storing schema for such purposes?